# [PHP][MySQL] Erased table after 60 seconds of recording

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timestamp

Im working on kinda program which main part is to count the time which user spent on website, and then to save recorded time in database.

How it works: on the page user has button to start recording his time, then he gets moved to another page, where he can save his time. Saved time is being sent to the php file (through ajax), and then php file puts value in database for current user.

**THE PROBLEM** is that after 60 seconds of recording time - table in database starts from scratch (00:00:00). For example: if user has already recorded 30 seconds (00:00:30), then he runs the script, records 40 seconds more, and then instead of 00:01:10 in database his score is clear (00:00:00)

Details below.

MySQL Table - type: time

//JS

```
$("#stopTimer").click(function(event) {
    var time = event.timeStamp;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        url: 'timer.php',
        data: {time: time}
    });
});
```

//PHP

```
$time = ($_POST['time']/1000);
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET timeOnline = timeOnline + '$time' WHERE memberID = :memberID");
$stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $memberID));
```

Comment: Which part exactly doesn't behave as you expect it to? JS? PHP? SQL? Extract a minimal but complete example (your's is neither), as it stands, your question is off-topic.

Comment: Not really sure which one, I guess that updating database might be the problem here. Updating fails after 1 min of recorded time. For example - You cant record more than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add seconds to a `TIME` column use `+ INTERVAL x SECOND`:

```
UPDATE members
SET timeOnline = timeOnline + INTERVAL :time SECOND
WHERE memberID = :memberID
```

Comment: Not really sure how to implement it, trying ti figure out how to put $time variable inside Your's code.

Comment: @piotrSatlawa `$stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $memberID, ':time' => $time));`

Answer (score 0):

Try it in another way.
Keep one extra column named `start_time` . When user first press this button store current time on that. 
When user browse in different pages, just calculate the time difference in `timeOnline` .
It will also be simpler.

Comment: Hm, it might be, but Im not really sure if it will help with updating time in database, becouse if user records more then 60 second in single session it isnt recorded then.

Comment: Why it will not be recorded? You will just a subtraction between `start_time` and `current time`.